# Laptop port not working

Tags: virtual-console, snap-store, viewports

Recently I updated my system running Ubuntu Mate 22.04. Now neither of the ports are working, nor am I able to access virtual keyboard. On top of that, I can't see *Snap Store* in the laptop. My built-in keyboard doesn't work, so I had to use an external keyboard.